# How to create two postgres database when docker-compose up?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y  \
&& apt-get install -y gcc gunicorn3 libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev libnss3 libnss3-dev wget \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt -f install -y

WORKDIR /App

COPY requirements.txt /App/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /App/
>! RUN pip install django~=4.1.1

RUN mkdir -p /App/data/db/
RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /App/data/db/

EXPOSE 7000
EXPOSE 8001
```

`

I have **base-compose** file that contain database image, here is file content:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  shared_network:
   driver: bridge

services:
  testdb:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=develop_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - shared_network

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

include:
  - ./base-compose.yml

services:
  test_develop:
    container_name: test_develop
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:7000
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    env_file:
      - ./environments/.env.develop
    depends_on:
      - testdb
    networks:
      - shared_network
    links:
      - testdb
```

Here is my docker-compose-prod.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

include:
  - ./base-compose.yml

services:
  test_production:
    container_name: test_production
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    env_file:
      - ./environments/.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - testdb
    networks:
      - shared_network
    links:
      - testdb
```

when i run the **docker-compose up --build** it create **develop_db** but i want to create **prod_db** too.

I try to create two database names develop_db and prod_db, when docker-compose up --build.

I used these two commands to run both docker-compose file.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose up --build
docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up --build
```

Comment: @Greg, Thank you i just edit, please checked it.

Comment: well, it could be possible, let me try it.

Comment: @Tanveer ok. waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created **init.sql** file and add it into **docker-entrypoint-init.db**, this is how i did. Its better to create **psql** folder and add **init.sql** file into it.

Remove **- POSTGRES_DB=develop_db** this from the base-compose file and change it.

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  shared_network:
   driver: bridge

services:
  testdb:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # add here 
      - ./psql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - shared_network

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here is my **init.sql** file. I just created **DATABASE** simply make sure you create **DATABASE** using **USER** & **PASSWORD**.

```
-- Creation of DATABASE

CREATE DATABASE test_db;
CREATE DATABASE test_prod_db;
```

[[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can control this generally through environment variables.

A key concept here is that Compose has the notion of a *project*.  Everything in a Compose file is associated with a project, and the default Docker object names that Compose produces embed the project name.  You can override the project name using a `docker-compose -p` option or the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.  The project name defaults to the current directory name, so if you want to run two Compose setups from the same directory, you need to set the project name for one or the other.

The related note here is that your two Compose files are almost identical, except for the container names (which Compose can assign), the Docker-internal port number (which doesn't need to change), the specific environment file, and the host port.  You could flatten this out into a single Compose file that works in both environments, with the correct settings

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=develop_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

 test:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "${HOST_PORT:-8000}:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./environments/.env.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Now you can run

```bash
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=develop HOST_PORT=7000 docker-compose up -d --build
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=prod HOST_PORT=8000 docker-compose up -d --build
```

Compose will create a separate copy of this stack for each `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`: two networks (`develop_default` and `prod_default`), two volumes, two database containers, and two application containers.  The two environments will be logically separate from each other, even though they're running on the same host system.

Comment: thank you, but can we run it on a single network, or volume or database container but two different application containers? here different application I mean is that one port and 2nd port use the same project working directory.

Comment: You could (possibly [configure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) to have an explicit name), but I wouldn't as you've described the problem – you don't want your developers accidentally changing production data.

Comment: yes, its good practice, thank you David.